# Enumerating sets in a random order

Tags: algorithms, sets, randomness, enumeration

I have multiples arrays. I'd like to enumerate all sets containing exactly one item from each array in a (pseudo-)random order, without explicitly building the array of all sets.

Any solution, even with poor pseudo-randomization, is welcome.

EDIT: Example for clarity:

Say I have arrays

```
A = { a1, a2 }, B = { b1, b2 }, C = { c1 }
```

I want to enumerate all the sets containing exactly one ax, bx and cx

```
{ a1, b1, c1 }, { a1, b2, c1 }, { a2, b1, c1 }, { a2, b2, c1 }
```

I want to enumerate them in a random order. The naïve solution would be to enumerate them in an array, then shuffle this array. But the solution is huge and I don't want to store it explicitely in memory.

Comment: an example would help ? I can't clearly understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Which resources have you checked? Are you aware of algorithms for sampling permutations and/or subsets?

Comment: I don't just need sampling, I need the guarantee that each combination appears exactly once over the whole enumeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that you have arrays $A_1,\ldots,A_d$ of sizes $n_1,\ldots,n_d$. The total number of tuples is thus $n_1 \times \cdots \times n_d$. Given a number in the range $1,\ldots,n_1 \times \cdots \times n_d$, you can decipher it into a tuple (I leave this part to you). It now remains to compute a pseudorandom permutation of the numbers $1,\ldots,n_1 \times \cdots \times n_d$, another task I leave to you.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go! However, the same problem is postponed, how do I build my pseudorandom permutation of the said numbers without putting them into an array?

Comment: Julien, I'm afraid you'll have to figure this out on your own. If you get stuck, you can ask a new question.

Comment: @Julien (Pseudo-)Random number generation is  a topic with lots of literature and good library support. When generating *anything* random, you typically assume access to some source of random numbers, be it in theory or practice.